# "Secondary to" in a sentence - meaning

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **secondary to**?

As an example I have the following sentence:

*The medication is used in patients with varicose veins secondary to cardiovascular disease.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a common usage in medical contexts. The patients had cardiovascular disease (CVD) as their main or first complaint and then following on from that they developed the varicose veins as a consequence. Usually the secondary complaint is less serious which for most forms of CVD and most degrees of varicose veins would be the case.

Comment: So can it be interpreted as "resulting from" for example in this case?

Comment: That is what I meant by as a consequence.